# Area of the triangle formed by circumcenter, incenter and orthocenter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Lets say we have $\triangle$$ABC$ having $O,I,H$ as its circumcenter, incenter and orthocenter. How can I go on finding the area of the $\triangle$$HOI$.

I thought of doing the question using the distance (length) between $HO$,$HI$ and $OI$ and then using the Heron's formula, but that has made the calculation very much complicated. Is there any simple way to crack the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any triangle $\triangle ABC$, we will
abuse notation and use the same letter to represent
both a vertex and the angle at that vertex. Let

- $a, b, c$ be the side lengths $|BC|$, $|CA|$ and $|AB|$.
- $L = a + b + c$ be the perimeter.
- $c_X, s_X, t_X$ be $\cos X, \sin X, \tan X$ for any angle $X \in \{ A, B, C \}$.
- $R$ be the circumradius.

Let $I, O, H$ be the incenter, circumcenter and orthocenter.
Their [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Examples_of_special_points) are given by

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\alpha_I : \beta_I : \gamma_I &=& \sin A  : \sin B : \sin C &=& t_A c_A : t_B c_B : t_C c_C\\
\alpha_O : \beta_O : \gamma_O &=& \sin 2A : \sin 2B : \sin 2C &=& 2t_A c_A^2 : 2t_B c_B^2 : 2t_C c_C^2\\
\alpha_H : \beta_H : \gamma_H &=& \tan A : \tan B : \tan C &=& t_A : t_B : t_C
\end{array}$$

Let $\mathcal{A}_0$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be the area of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle IOH$, their ratio is given by

$$\frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathcal{A}_0} =
\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_I & \beta_I & \gamma_I\\
\alpha_O & \beta_O & \gamma_O\\
\alpha_H & \beta_H & \gamma_H
\end{bmatrix}\right|
= \frac{\mathcal{N}}{\delta_I\delta_O\delta_H}
$$
where $\;\begin{cases}
\delta_I &= \sin A + \sin B + \sin C\\
\delta_O &= \sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C\\
\delta_H &= \tan A + \tan B + \tan C
\end{cases}
\;$ and
$$\begin{align}\mathcal{N} 
&= \left|\det\begin{bmatrix}
t_A c_A & t_B c_B & t_C c_C\\
2t_A c_A^2 & 2t_B c_B^2 & 2 t_C c_C^2\\
t_A & t_B & t_C
\end{bmatrix}\right|
= 2t_A t_B t_C
\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}
c_A & c_B & c_C\\
c_A^2 & c_B^2 & c_C^2\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right|\\
&= 2t_A t_B t_C |(c_A - c_B)(c_B - c_C)(c_C - c_A)|
\end{align}
$$
Since $A + B + C = \pi$, $\delta_H = t_A + t_B + t_C = t_A t_B t_C$. 
Together with the relations,
$$\begin{cases}
\mathcal{A}_0 &= \frac12 R^2(\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin2C)\\
L &= 2R(\sin A + \sin B + \sin C)
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\delta_O = \frac{2\mathcal{A}_0}{R^2}\\
\delta_I = \frac{L}{2R}
\end{cases}
$$
We find
$$\frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathcal{A}_0} = \frac{2}{\delta_I\delta_O}|(c_A - c_B)(c_B - c_C)(c_C - c_A)|
= \frac{2R^3}{\mathcal{A}_0L}|(c_A - c_B)(c_B - c_C)(c_C - c_A)|
$$
Notice
$$c_A - c_B = \frac{-a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{2bc} - \frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2ac}
= \frac{(b-a)L(L-2a)}{2abc}$$
and similar expressions for $c_B - c_C, c_C - c_A$, we find
$$\frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathcal{A}_0}
= \left(\frac{2R^3}{\mathcal{A}_0L}\cdot\frac{L^3(L-2a)(L-2b)(L-2c)}{8a^3b^3c^3}\right)|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)|
$$
Recall the [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) and a beautiful relation between $\mathcal{A}_0$ and $R$:
$$16\mathcal{A}_0^2 = L(L-2a)(L-2b)(L-2c)\quad\text{ and }\quad
4\mathcal{A}_0 R = abc
$$
What's inside the parenthesis above can be simplified as

$$\frac{2R^3}{\mathcal{A_0}L}\cdot\frac{L^2\cdot16\mathcal{A_0}^2}{8(4\mathcal{A}_0R)^3}
= \frac{L}{16A_0^2} = \frac{1}{(L-2a)(L-2b)(L-2c)}$$
This leads to a reasonably simple ratio one can use to compute the area $\mathcal{A}$.

$$\frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathcal{A}_0} = \frac{|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)|}{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 4):

> Hint:
>
> $AH=2R\cos A$, $AI=4R\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}$, $OA=R$, $\angle OAH=2\angle OAI=B-C$
>
> $\triangle HOI=\triangle AHO-\triangle AHI-\triangle AIO$

Final answer $$2R^2\sin\dfrac{B-C}{2}\sin\dfrac{C-A}{2}\sin\dfrac{A-B}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

From the information of [incentre](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html) and [Euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line), we have:

\begin{align*}
  r  &= \frac{\Delta}{s} \\
  R  &= \frac{abc}{4\Delta} \\
  IH &= \sqrt{4R^{2}+2r^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2)} \\
  IO &= \sqrt{R(R-2r)} \\
  OH &= 9R^{2}-(a^2+b^2+c^2) \\
\end{align*}

It's do-able by using simple program in a computer.  You can also find the area bound $(\Delta HOI=\frac{d}{2} \times OH)$ by knowing the [distance bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter#Euler_line) between the incentre and the Euler line.

Answer (score 2):

If you compute the exact barycentric coordinates of $O,H,I$, the ratio $\frac{[OHI]}{[ABC]}$ [is given by a simple determinant](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/RouthTheorem.shtml). So, just exploit the first table on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) and perform some computation.

Answer (score 1):

A área do triângulo HOI do triângulo ABC de lados a=|BC|, b=|AC| e c=|AB| é dada por:
$AreaHOI=|\frac{1}{4}.\frac{\left|\begin{array}{} a & a^3 & 1 \\ b & b^3 & 1 \\ c & c^3 & 1 \\ \end{array}  \right| }{\left|\begin{array}{} 0 & a^2 & b^2 &1\\ a^2 & 0 & c^2&1 \\ b^2 & c^2 & 0&1 \\1&1&1&0 \end{array}  \right| }|$

Dedução: Seja o triângulo ABC, com o vértice A na origem do Sistema Cartesiano e C no semi eixo positivo x. Assim:

$A=(0,0)$

$B=(\frac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2b},\frac{2S}{b})$

$C=(b,0)$

$S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$

$p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

$AreaHOI=3.AreaGIO$

$AreaGIO=\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{array}{} xG & yG & 1 \\ xI & yI & 1 \\ xO & yO & 1 \\ \end{array}  \right| $

"Obtendo as coordenadas de G, I e O através  de suas respectivas fórmulas e fazendo substituições obtemos:"

$AreaHOI=3.\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{array}{} \frac{-a^2+3b^2+c^2}{6b} & \frac{2S}{3b} & 1 \\ \frac{-a+b+c}{2} & \frac{2S}{a+b+c} & 1 \\ \frac{b}{2} & \frac{b(a^2-b^2+c^2)}{8S} & 1 \\ \end{array}  \right| $

"Desenvolvendo, substituindo S, p e fatorando obtemos:"

$AreaHOI=\left|\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)}{16S}  \right| $

"Substituindo as expressões por determinantes (S no formato de área de Cayley-Menger), obtemos:"

$AreaHOI=|\frac{1}{4}.\frac{\left|\begin{array}{} a & a^3 & 1 \\ b & b^3 & 1 \\ c & c^3 & 1 \\ \end{array}  \right| }{\left|\begin{array}{} 0 & a^2 & b^2 &1\\ a^2 & 0 & c^2&1 \\ b^2 & c^2 & 0&1 \\1&1&1&0 \end{array}  \right| }|$